# private repository unrecognize tag version

Tags: composer-php

composer.json in main project

```
"require": {"namth/my-core": "1.7.1"},
"repositories": {
  "namth-my-core": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "my-core ssh"
}  
},
```

my-core have 1 tag version: 1.7.1

which correctly go to my-core private repo, in my-core composer.json

```
"require": {"namth/my-something": "^1.7.0"},
"repositories": { 
  "namth-my-mysomething": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "my-something ssh"
}
```

my-something have 1 tag version: 1.7.1

Problem was when I run "composer update", it return error like:

```
namth/my-core 1.7.1 requires namth/my-something ^1.7.0 -> no matching package found.
```

My private repository was stored in Atlatssian Stash. 
Am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`repositories` config is available only for root package - only your main project can add custom repositories. Repositories configured in dependencies will be ignored.

> Repositories are only available to the root package and the repositories defined in your dependencies will not be loaded. Read the [FAQ entry](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can't-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md) if you want to learn why.
>
> <sub>https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#repository</sub>

You need to add both repositories to `composer.json` of your project, to make it work:

```
"repositories": {
    "namth-my-core": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "my-core ssh"
    },
    "namth-my-mysomething": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "my-something ssh"
    }
},
```